# interop.MODI.dll not working in windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, .net, ocr, office-interop, windows-server-2012

I  am using Microsoft Document imaging tool for OCR functionality in my asp.net application. I have referred interop.MODI.dll in my project. It works fine in my local windows 7 dev environment. But when I move it to server which is winodws server 2012 environment. Its gives me a error.

Error Message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {40942A6C-1520-4132-BDF8-BDC1F71F547B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I have installed Microsoft document imaging tool in server.
Could anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Solution. Changed the Identity settings in IIS this solved the issue.